# How to parse JSON data in Dart 3 using records?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to parse JSON data in Dart 3 using Records, Pattern Matching, and JSON Destructuring?

Following is how it was in Dart 2.

**Model**

```
class Category {
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Category({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Category(
      id: data['id'] as int,
      title: data['title'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

**In API Repository Class method**

```
class ApiRepository {

Future<List<Category>> fetchCategory() async {
      final res = await get(...);

      List<dynamic> decodedData = jsonDecode(res.body);

      final fetchedCategories =
          decodedData.map((e) => Category.fromJson(e)).toList();

        return fetchedCategories;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
void main() async {
  final List<(String, int)> categories = await fetchCategory();
  for (var category in categories) {
    var (title, id) = category;
    print(title);
    print(id);
  }
}

// Returns multiple values in a record:
(String, int) category(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return (json['title'] as String, json['id'] as int);
}

Future<List<(String, int)>> fetchCategory() async {
  final res = await get(...);

  List<dynamic> decodedData = jsonDecode(res.body);

  final fetchedCategories = decodedData.map((e) => category(e)).toList();

  return fetchedCategories;
}
```

**make changes if needed.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

Since this is new to me, Here is what I have assumed. I am happy for feedbacks:

Let us simply see what pattern matching does.

Assuming our class as:

```
class Category {
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Category({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

}
```

Let us have a object. Plain old json

```
 var jsonObject = 
{
'title': 'Hello World',
'id': 10,
};
```

We can assign this object value using pattern matching. I prefer switch case. To be ideal considering all the safeguards.

```
Category? category;
switch (jsonObject) {
case {'id': int id, 'title': String title}:
category =  Category(id: id, title: title);
default:
}
```

Now if you print the id you will get 10.

```
print(category?.id);
```

With list of jsonObjects we can simply do:

```
 var jsonObjectList = [
{
'title': 'Hello World',
'id': 10,
},
    {
'title': 'Hello World 2',
'id': 11,
}, 
  ];


List<Category?> categories = jsonObjectList.map((json){
switch (json) {
case {'id': int id, 'title': String title}:
return Category(id: id, title: title);
default:
return null;
}
}).toList();
```

Seems like a lot of pain to avoid the OOP for complex cases.
**Note: This is my understanding. Please correct or comment your opinions as well so I can improve**

Comment: In your last example you could also use the new [switch expressions](https://dart.dev/language/branches#switch-expressions) syntax